# Using audioplayer.js, want to play next track by using controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have an accordion and audios on it. I want to make controls the next/prev. to get work. Now on click the `$(this)` tab toggling but the other is not opening and the next track is not playing.;( When pressing the next/prev controls want to open the next accordion and play track.
Here is my JS code for accordion:

```
  var next = jQuery('.my_music').find('.accordion-toggle');
  next.click(function(){
    jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    jQuery(".accordion-content").not(jQuery(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
  });
```

For switching next track:

```
jQuery('.next_music').click(function(){
  // jQuery(next).next().slideToggle('fast');
  // cl(this);
  jQuery(".accordion-content").not(jQuery(this).next()).slideUp('fast');    
});
```

https://www.bessetteweb.com/valjion/ - example here

Comment: You should place the link of your site instead of my *clonage*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
*(Removed my first answer... Tested this one. Workings! ;) )*

```
$(".next_music").click(function(){
    var actualAccordion = $(this).parent().parent().parent('.accordion-content');
    console.log("next clicked");


    // find the accordion below by getting it's parent's next element (".my_music_wrap").
    belowAccordion = actualAccordion.parent().next().children('.accordion-toggle').first();

    // Toggle it!
    if(belowAccordion.length>0){    // If an accordion is found
        actualAccordion.first().slideToggle('fast');    // Toggles actual accordion.
        belowAccordion.click()  //.slideToggle('fast');
        belowAccordion.next().first().children().children().children().children(".audioplayer-playpause").click();
    }else{
        alert('No other song to play!');    //Will happen on the next button of the fifth song.
    }
});



$(".prev_music").click(function(){
    var actualAccordion = $(this).parent().parent().parent('.accordion-content');
    console.log("prev clicked");


    // find the accordion below by getting it's parent's next element (".my_music_wrap").
    aboveAccordion = actualAccordion.parent().prev().children('.accordion-toggle').first();

    // Toggle it!
    if(aboveAccordion.length>0){    // If an accordion is found
        actualAccordion.first().slideToggle('fast');    // Toggles actual accordion.
        aboveAccordion.click()  //.slideToggle('fast');
        aboveAccordion.next().first().children().children().children().children(".audioplayer-playpause").click();
    }else{
        alert('No other song to play!');    //Will happen on the prev button of the first song.
    }
});
```

I renamed your `next` var, since was confusing.

Comment: I paste it on my site and something go wrong)) accordion open and closes random tabs) did u test it on the clonage?)

Comment: on it... It's more difficult than it looks ;)

Comment: Undestand) im doing it for two days and didnt do yet(

Comment: Woops... Still a problem on the fifth song... But I'm really close now.

Comment: Here we are! See the alert on 1st song prev click... And on 5th song next click ;) All done.

Comment: The funny thing, is that i'm learning jQuery with this kind of problem. Thanks to you! ;)

Comment: Now it's perfect ;)

Comment: There is still something with the two .mp3 in the header... AND I would try to trigger the 1st song instead of alerting "no more song".. To create a cycle effect... But, are you ok to continue on this ? You have the logic of the approach... And a couple new methods to look at on how they work (`next()`, `prev()`, `first()`, `parent()`, `children()`, etc...) ;)

Comment: You mean in the slider the next song is not playing when pressing next button?)

Comment: Right! **1st:** I would attribute them a different class.
Like `<audio class="headerAudio" ...`.
**2nd**: Attribute a `class="bodyAudio"` to the 5 ones we've done (You're not limitted to 5 btw!).
**3rd**: Define TWO listeners... Modify your existing one like: `$('.bodyAudio').bind('play', function (event) {`
and a second new listener like : `$('.headerAudio').bind('play', function (event) {` → Leading to a second brand new function to handle the *navigation* between elements...
SO... Need work and thinking!! But that would be my approach.

Comment: In clear... You use the `audioplayer.js` on 2 different layouts. So got the preserve what's done... And *duplicate* it all (Trigger AND modified function for the 2nd layout) to have a similar effect on your headers audio presentation.